# Create Spark DataFrame from nested dictionary

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of nested dictionaries, e.g. `ds = [{'a': {'b': {'c': 1}}}]` and want to create a spark DataFrame from it while **inferring schema of nested dictionaries**. Using `sqlContext.createDataFrame(ds).printSchema()` gives me following schema

```
root
 |-- a: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = true)
```

but what I need is this

```
root
 |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
```

The second schema can be created by first converting dictionaries to JSON and then load it with `jsonRDD` like this `sqlContext.jsonRDD(sc.parallelize([json.dumps(ds[0])])).printSchema()`. But this would be quite cumbersome for large files.

I thought about converting dictionaries to `pyspark.sql.Row()` objects hoping that dataframe will infer the schema, but it didn't work when dictionaries had different schemas (e.g. first was missing some key).

Is there any other way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help.

```
import json
ds = [{'a': {'b': {'c': 1}}}]
ds2 = [json.dumps(item) for item in ds]
df = sqlCtx.jsonRDD(sc.parallelize(ds2))
df.printSchema()
```

Then,

```
root
|-- a: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid that (see my question). I was hoping there is a way to do it without having to create RDD from dictionaries just to get it's schema.

Comment: Sorry for missing your middle paragraph.Unfortunately, 'infer schema from dictionary' feature deprecated now, I hope there is another way too.